# How can I use javascript to submit a form that is in another location of the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, elrte

Let's say I have this form in my page

```
<form id="myform" action="src/post.php" name="post" method="post" target="_blank">
<div id="editor"></div>
</form>
```

Which works flawlessly.
But I need to use a button from another location in the same file to submit that form by ID. It's like a trigger command, but I believe it can only be achieved by Javascript.

Comment: what do you mean with "call"? Submit the form? Access properties?

Comment: What action would triggr the submit?

Comment: not clear from your question, can you post fiddle?

Comment: Too many javascript files and stuff to post on fiddle, not even know if I would be able to do that. You're right, I didn't make it clear enough, I noticed that. Let me try to explain:

I have the <form id="myform"> and I need to use a button from another location in the same file to submit that form. It's like a trigger command, but I believe it can only achieved by Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next code

```
document.forms['post'].submit();
```

Comment: Thank you, Zealot. I have a question: document is the document itself, right? what does forms mean? The ID?

Comment: "post" is referring to the name of the form, document is a DOM object referring to the webpage itself.

Comment: Yes, all forms in web document are available in `document.forms` global variable by their names.

Comment: I still couldn't make it, work, should I place it before the </header>?

Comment: No, you can place this code in any <script type="text/javascript"> block.

Comment: So I did this:

JAVSCRIPT

`<script>function myForm()
{
document.forms['theditorform'].submit();
}
</script>
`


HTML

`<label>
<button onclick="myForm()" style="border: 0; background: transparent">
<img src="imagens2/document_save.png" alt="submit" /><br />
<span>EXPORTAR<br />PROJETO</span>
</button>
</label>`


It triggers the form, but I'm still getting an empty document.
Here: http://canvas.lucrebem.com.br

If you click the button named "EXPORTAR PROJETO", you'll get a blank page with some printer buttons.

But if you click the Save button on the editor, you'll get the proper page.

Comment: It seems that when I submit the from another location it is not including the <div id="editor"> that is withing the form.

Comment: I think you need to read up on how html forms work... Forms only submits data that are contained in `input` and `textarea` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a button with id `submitButton`, this should do the trick

```
<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

You could do

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: @user2197736: no, form is the tag name (I'm assuming you have only one form on the page).

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work, but it seems that when I submit the form from another location it is not including the `<div id="editor">` that is withing the form and that's why I'm getting a blank page.